# Using same jar with Spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I deploy a job on yarn cluster mode by spark-submit with my jar file. The job deployed every time I submitted with 'same jar file', but It upload to hadoop everytime it's submitted. I think it's unnecessary routine to upload same jar every time. Is there any way to upload once and do yarn jobs with the jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your spark jar in hdfs and then use --master yarn-cluster mode, this way you could save the time required to upload the jar to hdfs everytime.

Other alternatives is put your jar in spark classpath on every node which has the following drawbacks:

1. If you have more than 30 nodes it would be very tedious to scp your jar in each node.
2. If you hadoop cluster upgrades and there is a new installation of spark, you would have to reploy.

Comment: does not matter which pwd would it be in hdfs?

Comment: Just keep it at a location where your user (running the spark job) would have read access to.

Comment: no need any other configuration? when I put file on hdfs and did not set app resource path, It comes with error..

Comment: The problem is that you might be reading resource files from your node which acts as a driver in yarn-client mode. But when you run your job in yarn-cluster mode your driver is not the node from which you initiate the job, hence you would have to keep your resource files in hdfs.